# Calling JAR from Python

Tags: java, python, jar, io

I have the code below:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT 

p = Popen(['java', '-jar', 'action.jar'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
stdout1, stderr1 = p.communicate(input=sample_input1)
print "Result is", stdout1

p = Popen(['java', '-jar', 'action.jar'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
stdout2, stderr2 = p.communicate(input=sample_input2)
print "Result is", stdout2
```

Loading the jar takes a lot of time and is very inefficient. Is there any way to avoid reloading it the second time, in the second line p = Popen(...), i.e. just loading it once in the beginning and continue using that instance? I tried to remove the second line unsuccessfully, Python complains:

```
"ValueError: I/O operation on closed file".
```

Is there any solution to this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`communicate()` waits for the process to terminate, so that explains the error you're getting -- the second time you call it, the process isn't running any more.

It really depends on how that JAR was written, and the kind of input it expects. If it supports executing its action more than once based on input, and if you can reformat your input that way, then it would work. If the JAR does its thing once and terminates, there's not much you can do.

If you don't mind writing a bit of Java, you can add a wrapper around the classes in `action.jar` that takes both your sample inputs in turn and passes them to the code in the jar.

You can save on the cost of starting up the Java Virtual Machine, using a tool like [Nailgun](http://www.martiansoftware.com/nailgun/).